# Make new rows dependent on previous row values in Presto

Tags: sql, recursion, presto

I have new users being added to my table each day and I want to check for new users.  However, the table's data removes old rows after reaching a certain number of rows.  To keep my new rows accurate, I want to calculate the new users BASED on the PREVIOUS ROWS values.  So as long as I have one previous row available, my new row will always be accurate. If there is no previous row, the row should have a default value.

| Date | users_Today | New_users | All_users_To_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dec 6 | Allie, Jon | Allie, Jon | Allie, Jon |
| Dec 7 | Allie, Jon, Zach | Zach | Allie, Jon, Zach |

Currently I have:

```
WITH user_log_response AS (
    SELECT
        CAST(JSON_PARSE(user_log) AS MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>) AS user_map,
        date
    FROM user_log_response_table
),
names_and_dates AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        user_name AS user_name,
        date
    FROM user_log_response 
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(user_map) AS u(user_name, user_age)
),
user_names AS (
    SELECT
        date,
        ARRAY_JOIN(
            ARRAY_AGG(
                user_name
                ORDER BY
                    user_name
            ),
            ','
        ) users_today,
    FROM names_and_dates
    GROUP BY
        date
    ORDER BY
        date DESC
)
SELECT
    date,
    users_today
FROM user_names
```

Which results in this

| Date | users_Today |
| --- | --- |
| Dec 6 | Allie, Jon |
| Dec 7 | Allie, Jon, Zach |

If I store "all users to date" how can I calculate "new users" to equal previous row's "all users to date" minus "users today"

Also how can I calculate "all users to date" to equal previous row's "all users to date" plus current row's "new users"

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? You have asked several very similar questions already and I'm not very sure what is different here, what is the input data and desired result.

Comment: all solutions offered do not solve the issue of using previous row as input.  all solutions require that all original data is available.

Comment: the only available data is a table that holds users per day

Comment: What is "previous row" in your understanding? There were solutions which used previous rows to build the desired output (including provided by me).

Comment: yes you did, I did not see that.  I chose your answers as best.  Thanks so much!